# How to get my STUFF Function to work in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting the following query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT AlertID,
(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t2.LocationDesc
FROM app_Location t2
WHERE t1.LocationCode = t2.LocationCode
FOR XML PATH (''))
, 1, 1, '')) as Location,
CensusTime,
InsertDate
FROM MultiCensusEmail 
INNER JOIN app_Location t1 ON MultiCensusEmail.Location = t1.LocationCode
```

I want it to return a comma delimited list for the locations, but they are showing up on separate rows. 
[image: Non-delimited]

I want the row to end up something like this:

> 5A8056A7-5D8F-4678-B980-9E54987EE70C |     AS EMERGENCY DEPT, BN CARDIAC,
>   BN CHEST PAIN UNIT | 7:00 |   2016-10-17 9:17:55.067

Comment: Without looking at the data it is hard to fix.. Do you have more than one `LocationDesc` for a single `LocationCode` ?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Only one LocationDesc per LocationCode.

Comment: Use distinct in outer select..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted to do using COALESCE:

```
declare @Location varchar(max)

select @Location = COALESCE(@Location + ', ', '') + LocationDesc
From app_Location INNER JOIN MultiCensusEmail ON MultiCensusEmail.Location = app_Location.LocationCode
where upper(UserID) = 'test'

select distinct AlertID, @Location, CensusTime, InsertDate
from MultiCensusEmail
where upper(UserID) = 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much detail about your data, but I think that your JOIN is not needed.

```
SELECT AlertID,
    (STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t2.LocationDesc
    FROM app_Location t2
    WHERE MultiCensusEmail.Location = t2.LocationCode // probably you want another condition here
    FOR XML PATH (''))
    , 1, 1, '')) as Location,
    CensusTime,
    InsertDate
  FROM MultiCensusEmail
```

What do you want to "group by" (e.g. what data item does have multiple locations)?

The "outer" query should produce the wanted rows without "location" (in your case), and the "inner" FOR XML query should have a condition that filters the "locations" you want to have comma-separated.

Comment: What if he want don't want non matching records ?